# Add range of numbers

Tags: android, addition

I am trying to make an adding program which will add all the previous numbers to num, say num is four, so 1+2+3+4=10 an then return num.

How can I write the function SumNum(num)?

Comment: Could you please share what you have already tried?

Comment: Note: This question isn't specific to Android. Are you using Java/Kotlin/Xamarin (C#) Flutter or other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it will always be from 1 to N ( 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + ... + N), you could use the following formula:
Sum = ((A0 + An)*n)/2. That is the equation for the sum of arithmetic progression

```
function int SumNum(num){
  return ((1 + num)*num)/2;
}
```

Comment: That works as an explanation for the formula. Nice addition.

Comment: this did the trick, sumadd(num)
if (num == 1) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return num * SumAddi(num - 1);
  }